# Spring MVC @ExceptionHandler failing to catch an exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, exception, multipartform-data

I'm using *Spring MVC* to receive a file that is being uploaded with a form. This is my *Controller* that receives the request and handles possible exceptions:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                headers = {"content-type=multipart/form-data"}, 
                produces = "application/xml")
public @ResponseBody MyStuff processFormUpload( @RequestParam("file") CommonsMultipartFile file) throws 
    //return beautiful xml response generated from the input file;
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView exceptionHandler(Exception ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //return pretty exception page;
}
```

This is how I initialized the file resolver:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

Everything works beautifully even when exceptions are raised while generating the response. The only problem is when someone tries to upload a file that is bigger than the **maxUploadSize**. In this case the exceptionHandler does not catch the exception and the service returns an ugly Internal **Error 500** caused by `MaxUploadSizeExceededException`.

How can I configure my web app to catch that kind of exception as well? I'd like to use `@ExceptionHandlers` and not having to change the project structure too much.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding goes, these exceptions are thrown during data binding, before the controller is actually reached, therefore resulting in a 500 and no calling of the exception handler method.

So far the only way I have figured out to handle what you have mentioned is for the controller to implement 'HandlerExceptionResolver' and provide implementation for:

```
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception)
```

I agree, it does not look at elegant or flexible as an @ExceptionHandler. Hope this helps.